# Numerical ways to find energy eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

I have to find energy eigenvalues of (time dependent) Schrödinger equation, but it was nonlinear so i cannot find a appropriate solutions about it.

I am not good at numerical analysis, so i don't know what kinds of methods are normally used in quantum mechanics. Also i cannot understand some methods which i can find in google scholar or arxiv (cause they are too difficult for me).

So, my question is that there is a computational method which is usually used in numerical researches in quantum mechanics and also simple as possible to applied by student?

Sorry for my english

Comment: + I cannot find any orthonormal basis of it. Sorry for my basic question...

Comment: A wide range of numerical techniques are used in quantum mechanics. Can you give us some more information about the problem you are trying to solve. Do you only want the eigenvalues, or do you want the eigenfunctions as well? or do you need something else? What kind of accuracy do you require? How many eigenvalues do you need and which ones? What sort of physical system are you considering? Single particle systems? Many particle systems (and if so how many particles are we talking about)?  Something else? Different techniques are used in different contexts

Comment: You should probably also investigate whether there are preexisting software packages that deal with the system you are considering, rather than re-implementing from scratch (although it is against this site's policy to answer questions on software recommendations). You may also want to consider whether your question may be better suited to [computational science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can you provide the nonlinear Schrodinger equation you are trying to simulate? e.g.) is it Gross-Pitaevskii equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [variational method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)), especially numerical procedures based on the [Ritz method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritz_method), to find an approximation for the lowest energy eigenvalue of the time-independent Schrödinger equation.

Comment: But i have to find more than 100+ energy eigenvalues for my research...

Comment: Also my systems Hamiltonian is time dependent, so lowest energy will be changed when times evolute.

Comment: That's not a terribly good answer unless you give some details on the procedure.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - I agree that you could write more about it, but I gave the links to the relevant  wikipedia articles where it is explained in more detail, which should be a first help. Please feel free to elaborate on the method in a more elaborate answer.

Comment: @freecharly the problem is: I don’t think it possible to supply with someone that is computationally challenged a suitable answer unless one has a link to some pre-canned routine.